# a fast way to get human genome sequence by coordinate

Tags: python, sequence, bioinformatics, genome

I want to get a lot human genome fragments (more than 500 million of them) randomly.

This is a partial work of the whole process. I have .sam result file from bowtie, with 10 million human genome reads alignment. I want to compare each query reads with the 'reference sequence it aligned to' from the sam file. The reference sequence I used is hg19.fa from UCSC. So I need to be able to get the sequence from hg19.fa (or chromosome files) by using the location in the sam file.

e.g. with giving: chr4:35654-35695, i could get 42bp sequences:

gtcttccagggtttttatatttttgggttttacacttaagt

so far, i had 2 solutions:
1. python script to fetch sequences from UCSC DAS server:
http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/das/hg19/dna?segment=chr4:35654,35695

1. using python script call ''samtools faidx'' command and return commnad output,
   from post:
   http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=23606&highlight=fetch+genome+coordinate

but, they are slow. samtools faidx is bit faster than getting it from DAS server, but still slow.

so, is there any **FAST** way to do this? i have the seprate chromosome fasta files, and hg19.fa file.

Comment: If you are getting a ceiling, You might be limited by your bandwidth/ wire if fetching from external sources.  Similarly, if reading, limited by the read speed of the disk if not in active memory.

Comment: Have you considered using [pysam](https://code.google.com/p/pysam/)?  You can use it to open a sam file and continually call faidx without having the opening/closing overhead by using `subprocess.call('samtools faidx')`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

use **ucsc**  **twoBitToFa**  in  http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/admin/exe/linux.x86_64/

see also http://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/twoBit.html

Comment: i have hg19 in 2bit format, can you tell a bit more about how should i use this file in my situation? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the python twobitreader module:

python -m twobitreader hg19.2bit < temp.bed

http://pythonhosted.org/twobitreader/